# Undefined JSON Result ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

For some reason my JSON result is undefined. Here is my JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON("/BMICalculations/GetJSONData", function (data) {
                var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
                div.html("<br/> " + "Persons received from server: " + "<br/>");
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    printBMI(div, item);
                });

            });
        });
    });

    function printBMI(div, item) {
        div.append("<br/>" + "BMI: " + item.BMIInfo);
    }
```

And here is my controller code:

```
  public JsonResult GetJSONData()
    {
        var x = db.BMICalculations.ToList();
        var last = x.Last();
        var data = new
        {
           BMICalculation = last.BMICalc,
           BMIInfo = last.BMIMeaning
        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The webpage shows the word 'undefined'

Here is a pic:

[image]

Comment: can you show the json reponse which is returned?

Comment: check the browser console via firebug or fiddler what is server returning ins ajax call response

Comment: Your client side code is expecting an array of items, while server side sends just one object. Decide on something

Comment: Currently, `$.each()` is iterating over the the properties of the single object, `var data = new { BMICalculation = last.BMICalc, BMIInfo = last.BMIMeaning };`. If you want to iterate a collection, the server needs to provide that collection of objects. Not just the `.Last()`.